# How to substitute ?column? from subqueries output

Tags: postgresql, select, subquery

How I can put name on subquery's output, instead of `?column?`?

The `SELECT`'s output is:

```
._______.__________.__________.
|__id___|_?column?_|_?column?_|
|_31886_|____12____|____13____|
```

What I want is:

```
._______.__________.__________.
|__id___|___ages___|_validate_|
|_31886_|____12____|____13____|
```

What my `SELECT` look like:

```
SELECT g.id,
(select dt from pcdhidro where nomepcd=31886 order by datahora asc limit 1),
(select dt from pcdhidro_2003_96 where nomepcd=31886)
FROM gestpcd_2 g
WHERE g.tipo = 'HIDRO' and g.id = 31886
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(Select X from Y) AS alias
```

So in your case:

```
SELECT g.id,
(select dt from pcdhidro where nomepcd=31886 order by datahora asc limit 1) as ages,
(select dt from pcdhidro_2003_96 where nomepcd=31886) as validate
FROM gestpcd_2 g
WHERE g.tipo = 'HIDRO' and g.id = 31886
```